# How do you prevent JAXB from creating an intermediate object

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I want to have the following XML

```
<doc>
   <items>
      <item />
      <item />
      <item />
   </items>
   <things>
      <thing />
      <thing />
      <thing />
   </things>
</doc>
```

The schema would be something like

```
<schema>
   <element name="doc">
      <complexType>
          <all>
              <element name="items" minOccurs="1">
                  <complexType>
                       <sequence>
                           <element name="item" minoccurs="0" maxoccurs="unbounded" />
                       </sequence>
                  </complexType>
              </element>
              <element name="things" minOccurs="1">
                  <complexType>
                       <sequence>
                           <element name="thing" minoccurs="0" maxoccurs="unbounded" />
                       </sequence>
                  </complexType>
              </element>
          </all>
      /<complexType>
   </element>
</schema>
```

Now with JAXB it creates a class called Doc which would have an Items type which has an Item. Therefor to add the first element I have to do this.

```
Doc doc = new Doc();
Items items = new Items();
items.getItem().add(new Item());
doc.setItems(items);
```

I would like to be able to do the following instead:

```
Doc doc = new Doc();
doc.getItems().add(new Item());
```

Or even better:

```
Doc doc = new Doc();
doc.addItem(new Item());
```

Anyway of doing this through JAXB bindings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the [comment by nsfyn55](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10323787/how-do-you-prevent-jaxb-from-creating-an-intermediate-object/10323938#comment13295534_10323873), there does not seem to be any way to do this with bindings.

However, if you were using JAXB annoations, you could do:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Doc {
    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "items")
    @XmlElement(name="item")
    List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();

    public void addItem(Item item) {
        this.items.add(item);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: thanks but I am trying to do it with bindings rather than annotations.

Comment: not sure if I should mark this as the "best" answer because my question was specifically to use "bindings" not annotations.

Comment: Updated the answer to include nsfyn55's explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You need the wrapper tag. It is what defines the elements as a grouped sequence and not just a bunch of arbitrary elements.

Comment: do you have an example of this?

Comment: thats what I am getting at. There is no solution to this problem besides what beerbajay suggested. The way the xsd is interpreted necessarily leads you to the structure you find problematic. If you read the JAXB spec you'll find that binding and validating xml is actually quite complicated and has a lot of edge cases. The annoying two layer access of list items serves to ensue the model is complete

Comment: Thanks so I guess there is no actual solution for this question at the moment with the present standards then.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to be able to do the following instead:
>
> Doc doc = new Doc();
>
> doc.getItems().add(new Item());

I believe that you can, (at least up to JAXB 2.1) the generated code for getItems() would check for a null member collection, and create it if necessary before returning it. So it always returns a 'live' list object.

Comment: Not sure what version I am at at the moment but no the getItems() may return a null.  It would be great if it didn't.

Comment: Could you post the generated code for this method, maybe ? Also, IMHO, it is fairly critical that you be able to assert which version of JAXB API, and which version of the JAXB Impl you are running against.